# Approaches when learning from huge datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, large-data, model-evaluation, train

Basically, there are two common ways to learn against huge datasets (when you're confronted by time/space restrictions):

1. Cheating :) - use just a "manageable" subset for training. The loss of accuracy may be negligible because of the law of diminishing returns - the predictive performance of the model often flattens out long before all the training data is incorporated into it.
2. Parallel computing - split the problem into smaller parts and solve each one on a separate machine/processor. You need a parallel version of the algorithm though, but good news is that a lot of common algorithms are naturally parallel: nearest-neighbor, decision trees, etc.

Are there other methods? Is there any rule of thumb when to use each? What are the drawbacks of each approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stream Mining is one answer. It is also called:

- Data Stream Mining
- Online Learning
- Massive Online Learning

  Instead of putting all data set in memory and training from it. They put chunks of it in memory and train classifier/clusters from these stream of chunks. See following links.
- [Data_stream_mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_stream_mining) from wikipedia.
- MOA: Massive Online Analysis

  - [Article](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/bifet10a/bifet10a.pdf)
  - [Tool](http://moa.cs.waikato.ac.nz/), written in Java, able to use weka algorithms
  - [Book](http://moa.cs.waikato.ac.nz/2011/02/10/book-adaptive-stream-mining-pattern-learning-and-mining-from-evolving-data-streams/)
- [Mining of Massive Datasets Book](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/book.pdf) , From Stanford University. It uses MapReduce as a tool.
- Videos in videolectures.net. Search it similar videos exists in that site.

  - [State of the Art in Data Stream Mining](http://videolectures.net/ecml07_mohamed_sad/)
  - [Mining Massive Data Sets](http://videolectures.net/mmdss07_fogelman_mmds/)

Comment: agreed, the MOA toolbox would be a good place to start

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using just one subset, you could use multiple subsets as in mini-batch learning (e.g. stochastic gradient descent). This way you would still make use of all your data.

Comment: Aha that's a good point - I clarified the question. I'm interested in a scenario when you're confronted with time/space restrictions and "cannot afford" mini-batch learning.

Answer (score 1):

Ensembles like bagging or blending -- no data is wasted, the problem automagically becomes trivially parallel and there might be significant accuracy/robustness gains.